# Only allow access to a port when connected to VPN

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, firewall, openvpn, centos7

I am running a Centos 7 server with OpenVpn on an amazon ec2 server. How can I configure it to only allow access to ports 2087 and 2083 when I am connected to the VPN, but not when I am not connected. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear, what do you mean by - "but not when I am not connected." how exactly are you using centos 7. Is it router or are you connecting from the server itself? When you connected to the openvpn server - is it become a default router for a client?

Comment: I am using Centos 7 as a web server for a website. I am connecting to the server itself. It is not the default router for the client.

Comment: When you are connected to the openvpn server where do you need access to the ports (2087/2083) - on the server itself or outside?

Comment: outside. the ports 2087 and 2083 serve up webpages that i don't want an outsider to be able to view unless they are connected to the VPN

Comment: Pretty much by definition, a user who is connected to a VPN is, at that point, considered "inside," not "outside."

Comment: Ok, so I mean that I want someone on the "inside" to be able to access those ports, but someone on the "outside" could not. @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: This should be as simple as this: Don't open the ports in the security group, and, when you access the services on these ports, access the machine using its internal IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, so I mean that I want someone on the "inside" to be able to access those ports, but someone on the "outside" could not.

you cab just block the ports from the outside

```
# iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083 -j DROP
```

and open from inside

```
# iptables -I INPUT -i tun+ -p tcp -m multiport --dports 2087,2083 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: The first command that blocks the IP's works, but the second command doesn't do anything. After I run the first command, the DNS on ports 2087 and 2083 are still not resolving @ALex_hha

Comment: What about default policy in the INPUT/OUTPUT chains?