# Allow access to all ports on public IP only when connected using VPN

Tags: iptables, openvpn

Currently I'm unable to access some ports on my public IP over VPN, which is understandable since I've set the `INPUT` default policy to `DROP`. How can I configure the `iptables` to allow access to all available ports only when I'm connected via VPN?

I've searched similar questions here, e.g. the most similar one: [Only allow access to a port when connected to VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/766587/only-allow-access-to-a-port-when-connected-to-vpn). However, the difference is that my server and the VPN server are on the same machine. Furthermore, all the answers didn't seems to solve the problems.

Below are my current `iptables` config (my public IP is on interface `eno1`, and the VPN is on `tun0`):

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eno1 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eno1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eno1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Here is config on the nat table:

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an iptables rule to allow everything from tun devices like -

```
  -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

(A "+" after the interface name is like a wildcard, so its equivalent to tun*, and assumes that any tun interface is a VPN interface.  You might get away with -i tun0)

Comment: I've applied `-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT` as in my question above (since its only one interface actually), but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you certain the relevant application is listening on the tun0 interface?  Its not uncommon for some applications to only bind to specific interfaces. Does TCPDUMP show the packet coming into the network?

Comment: Also, what has NAT got to do with your problem?  Is the service running on this server, or is this device a router and you need to forward the input to another system on your network?

Comment: The application is bind to `::`, thus as I understand it should cover all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces. And I can confirm that I can access the application by accessing it via the VPN server IP (e.g. 10.8.0.1). However I can't access it via my public IP (e.g. 103.153.112.14). The nat might not have any relation to my problem (as it is only a single server), but I've just include it just as an additional details to my question.

Comment: What software is the application?  What you have written about accessing it "via the VPN server IP" makes no sense.  Is 10.8.0.1 an IP on the same machine that runs the VPN server and is this the same machine that hosts the application?    What traffic do you see if you run "tcpump -n -i ANY port XXXX"   and make a remote request ?

Comment: It's [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/). My mistake, sorry for the confusion there, 10.8.0.1 is an IP on the same machine runs the VPN server (an IP which assigned to `tun0`), and its on the same machine which host the app. This is the traffic by running `tcpump -n -i any port 4646` https://hastebin.com/ijezokowaw.css.

Comment: To make it clearer, I couldn't access the app via public IP, e.g. http://103.153.112.14:4646. I'm perfectly fine accessing it via VPN IP when connected, e.g. http://10.8.0.1:4646. However, I'm just curious if there are any way so that I could also access the http://103.153.112.14:4646 when connected to VPN.

Comment: Ah, OK, your problem has nothing to do with iptables.  It has to do with policy routing.  When the VPN is up, I'm guessing it sets up a default route across the VPN, so thats the path outbound traffic takes - but it doesnt work because of egress filtering.  The solution (which is easy to say but a bit tricky to implement) is to do policy based routing, ie route traffic out based on the IP address.   Google "policy based routing linux" for tutorials on it.